# Why are records from my data-modifying CTE not appearing in the subsequent SELECT from the insertion table?

Tags: postgresql

I've crafted what seems to be a rather clever query for only inserting records that don't exist, and then returning the ids for all inserted data rows, with each row's PK id, whether it's been inserted or not (avoiding a lot of the problems that come with `ON CONFLICT... RETURNING id` clauses). The only problem is, it doesn't return the data that's been inserted, which doesn't make sense to me:

In postgres 12.3:

```sql
CREATE TABLE target_table (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  value JSONB NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (name, value)
);

INSERT INTO target_table(name, value) VALUES ('asdf', '18446744073709551615');
INSERT INTO target_table(name, value) VALUES ('asdf', 'null');


-- merge query
WITH incoming AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('asdf','null'::JSONB), ('asdf', '18446744073709551615'::JSONB), ('asdaf', '3'::JSONB)) AS tmp(name, value)
)
, merge_op AS (
    INSERT INTO target_table(name, value)
    SELECT i.name, i.value
    FROM incoming i
    LEFT JOIN target_table er
        ON er.name = i.name
        AND er.value = i.value
    WHERE er.name IS NULL
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
)
SELECT er.id, er.name, er.value
FROM target_table er
JOIN incoming i ON i.name = er.name
AND i.value = er.value;
```

Since this is all one statement, it all happens in the same transaction, so I'd think that the last `SELECT` statement would be able to 'see' the inserted records and join appropriately. What happens is, the last record (with a `value` of `3`) doesn't get returned on the first run of the merge query; only the first two existing records are returned. A subsequent run (inserting 0 records this time) will return all incoming records.

Short of running the last `SELECT` in a separate query, can this be done? Any unforeseen drawbacks to this approach?

Answer (score 2):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see Chapter 13), **so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables**. (... ) and means that RETURNING data is the only way to communicate changes between different WITH sub-statements and the main query.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So you need a RETURNING clause in your `merge_op` clause to see the inserted rows.

```
-- merge query
WITH incoming (name, value) AS (
  VALUES 
    ('asdf','null'::JSONB), 
    ('asdf', '18446744073709551615'::JSONB), 
    ('asdaf', '3'::JSONB)
)
, merge_op AS (
    INSERT INTO target_table(name, value)
    SELECT i.name, i.value
    FROM incoming i
    LEFT JOIN target_table er
        ON er.name = i.name
        AND er.value = i.value
    WHERE er.name IS NULL
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
    returning *
)
SELECT er.id, er.name, er.value
FROM merge_op er;
```

If you also want to see the rows from `incoming` that were not inserted (e.g. due to a conflict) you need an outer join:

```
SELECT er.id, i.name, i.value
FROM incoming i 
  LEFT JOIN merge_op er 
         ON i.name = er.name
        AND i.value = er.value;
```

Comment: The objective was to get the whole set of incoming values, augmented with their (either existing or newly created) surrogate ids. It looks like that can be accomplished with a UNION? `SELECT er.id, er.name, er.value
FROM target_table er
JOIN incoming i ON i.name = er.name
 AND i.value = er.value
UNION 
SELECT * FROM merge_op`

Comment: `the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable` is unintuitive at first, but I suppose that makes sense.

Comment: I re-worded the question; after a re-read it seems I expressed the expected output incorrectly.

Comment: The LEFT JOIN will return the whole set of "incoming" values.

Comment: But not with the new ids for the inserted values. If records exist: `1 | a, 2 | b` and I insert a `c`, what I wanted returned is `1 | a, 2 | b, 3 | c`

Comment: @BrDaHa: sorry I had a typo. The final SELECT needs to select from the `merge_op` not from the table.

Comment: that still doesn't work, unfortunately: if a record in `incoming` already exists in the `target_table`, then the ids for those records are returned as `NULL`. Is there something wrong with the `UNION` approach?

Comment: Under concurrency, my proposed query seems to be failing to return data under certain circumstances: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql